# search in a date range

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm REALLY stuck.  I have a db table that lists properties that have booked time slots.  I need to search the table for a date range.  The issue with my current query is that if a listed date in the table falls outside of the queried date range then the query does not return the correct results.
here is a sample of the table `propty_availability`

```
id  BeginDate   EndDate     propid
1   2018-10-02  2018-10-10  155855
2   2018-12-15  2018-12-22  159170
3   2018-12-22  2018-12-25  155855
4   2018-12-26  2018-12-29  155855
5   2018-12-05  2018-12-15  155019
6   2018-11-20  2018-11-27  155855
7   2018-12-18  2018-11-27  155655
```

My query is:

```
SELECT propid FROM propty_availability
            WHERE 
                (BeginDate BETWEEN '2018-12-20' AND '2018-12-27') 
                        AND 
                (EndDate BETWEEN '2018-12-20' AND '2018-12-27')
```

The problem is that this query will return record 3 and 6 only because the date ranges booked include the full date range queried.
I tried OR instead of AND between begindate and enddate but that gave me records  that either included begindate or enddate.  Anything that is in the table that has one of the columns that fall outside of the queried date don't get listed.

How do I get the query to show me rows that anything falling between my query dates and correspond to the dates in the table?
Expected result is for rows 2, 3, 4, 6, 7  to be listed because each have dates within the range queried.
Feel free to ask questions as I am not familiar with how to post code and tables in here..

Comment: `gave me records that either included begindate or enddate. Anything that is in the table that has one of the columns that fall outside of the queried date don't get listed.`  This is contradictory.  `OR` should be the solution here.  Edit:  Row 6 and 7 don't fall between the dates,  Row 7 is actually reversed.  I think I understand your problem if 6 and 7 are supposed to be 2019.

Comment: Yes, sorry, 7 is reversed, so ignore it.  Problem is I tried OR.  It still doesn't work if the dates are outside of the required queried date. For example, if a row has 2018-12-19 and 2018-12-28 then it won't be returned.  The issue is that I need to return rows that the queried date falls into.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Going by brute-force here...

```
SELECT propid FROM propty_availability
WHERE 
(BeginDate BETWEEN '2018-12-20' AND '2018-12-27' OR BeginDate < '2018-12-20') 
AND 
(EndDate BETWEEN '2018-12-20' AND '2018-12-27' OR EndDate > '2018-12-20')
```

So, the possible cases are:

1. Your queried begins before your period but ends during it
2. It's neatly inside it
3. Starts during the period but ends after it
4. Overlaps completely
5. Its completely ouside

A little graphical aid:

```
                 |---------------------|            # Period
              +-----+ +-----+ +-----------+         # 1, 2, 3
              +---------------------------+         # 4
        +-----+                           +-------+ # 5 (x2)


1:    (false OR true) AND (true OR true)  = true
2:    (true OR false) AND (true OR true)  = true
3:    (true OR false) AND (false OR true)  = true
4:    (false OR true) AND (false or true)  = true 
5:    (false OR true) AND (false OR false) = false
5(2): (false o false) AND (false OR false)  = false
```

Logic test (in php)

```
is_range_in_range(1, '2018-12-17', '2018-12-22');
is_range_in_range(2, '2018-12-22', '2018-12-25');   
is_range_in_range(3, '2018-12-23', '2018-12-30');   
is_range_in_range(4, '2018-12-17', '2018-12-30');
is_range_in_range(5, '2018-12-01', '2018-12-15');   
is_range_in_range(5, '2018-12-29', '2018-12-31');       
is_range_in_range(6, '2018-11-18', '2018-11-27');

function is_range_in_range($c, $b, $e) {
    $bDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2018-12-20');
    $eDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2018-12-27');

    $b = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $e);
    $e = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $e);

    echo $c . " " . ((($b >= $bDate && $b <= $eDate) || ($b  < $bDate)) 
    && (($e >= $bDate && $e <= $eDate) || ($e > $bDate)) ? 'true' : 'false') . "\n";
}
```

Note that `endDate > beginDatePeriod` is not a typo.

Output:

```
1 true
2 true
3 true
4 true
5 false
5 false
6 false
```

Comment: didn't try this but I don't know if it can work either because I don't want results that fall out of the queried date range either.  Won't this return a result that gives me all rows that are simply less than or greater than the begin and end dates respectively?

Comment: @you1ca I think it's solid, but who knows... only one way to know for sure. It's six test cases... I'll get back to you in a jiff...

Comment: NOPE, sorry, it did not work.  It now gave me zero results!

Comment: almost...I think the issue now is that it returns all dates from outside of the range.  Need to limit the search to include results only up to the date but within the range.    I don't know if that just confuses...   What about a row that is listed as   8   2018-11-18  2018-11-27  155655?   This row would show up.  But really it shouldn't because it is nowhere in the queried range, although with your query it does because technically startdate is less than the queried date.  Any way to limit that?

Comment: @you1ca ran the test with your values (2018-11-18 2018-11-27) and returned `false`. You might need to group your operators as I did in the php ? Let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: This worked!  Thank you soooo much!   I forgot to change my OR to an AND.